# For e.value[#] what exactly does the number (#) represent with respect to a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google apps and I am sorry if this is a dumb question.
I have look through the web to try and figure this out, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I made a form that would send response to sheet.
In the sheet, I am trying to set var to certain cell, so I am trying to use e.value to accomplish this. For example:

```
var submitDate = e.values[0];
var submitEmail = e.values[1];
var submitName = e.values[2];
```

I am not very certain what the numbers in brackets, in this case 0, 1, and 2, means. Does that mean the 1st 2nd and 3rd response from the form? The 1st 2nd and 3rd cell in the response sheet? Or the 1st 2nd and 3rd response in the sheet edited?
Please help shed some light on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Read about / study how JavaScript arrays are used. More generically, bracket notation is one of the syntaxes used for object property access

Answer (score 0):

Index (0-based) of [Array with values in the same order as they appear in the spreadsheet.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) Here the "spreadsheet" is the Form Responses one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete event object from a simple one question form:

`{"authMode":{},"values":["2/27/2019 20:44:34","Blue"],"namedValues":{"What is the color of the highest intensity light that comes unrefracted into the earths atmosphere?":["Blue"],"Timestamp":["2/27/2019 20:44:34"]},"range":{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":35,"rowEnd":35,"columnEnd":2},"source":{},"triggerUid":"472778"}`

values is the array of values that were submitted to the linked sheet.  I believe the first one which is values[0] is a time stamp and the values[i] is the answer to the first question.  In this case there is only one question so that's all there is.

- [It's all explained here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: I think I follow.
Suppose I add a column in the response sheet that is capturing response from the form in front of the time stamp column, will the time stamp now be Value[1] or will it still be Value[0]?

Comment: I don't think so.  I believe that information comes directly from the form response not from the spreadsheet.  But if you wish to try it let me know how it works.